# how to fix failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible when using WCF test client

Tags: .net, wcf

When adding service from WCF test client getting failed to add a service error.
I have tried running WCF service in local. Still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

In IIS->WebSite[XYZ]->Bindings->Http->Your machine IP config[10.A.B.C] and click on Add button.

Add service in WCF test client http://10.A.B.C/Service/Q3.svc

It works